# Select author with max percentage of unread books in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

When I want to select author and number of books that are read. I will use the following statement

```
select authorid, count(authorid)
from books
where read = 1
group by authorid
```

When I want to select number of unread books for a given author I will change `1` to `0` in the above statement.

I'd like to select for each `authorid` the ratio `unread/all` and from all these ratios select the `authorid` with `max(unread/all)`.

Can I create such a statement? The max ratio is `1`. If there are more `authorid`s with max ratio (e.g. ratio = 1) you can return all of them, random of them or limit to 1 (this doesn't matter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all the ratios is like this:

```
select authorid,
       SUM(case when read = 0 then 1 else 0 end)/count(authorid) as ratio
from books b
group by authorid
```

---

And this will get you the ones with the biggest ratio:

```
select b.authorid, max(aux.ratio) as maxRatio
from books b
inner join(
    select authorid,
           SUM(case when read = 0 then 1 else 0 end)/count(authorid) as ratio
    from books b
    group by authorid) aux on b.authorid = aux.authorid
group by b.authorid
```

Comment: The first statement is nice. I didn't know this conditional counting. But the second statement won't select only the maximum ratio.

Comment: This solution is correct. Intead of the second `select` statement I used `order by ratio`.

Comment: But it was necessary to use `cast(count(authorid) as float)` in the division expression.

Answer (score 1):

I can not test this ATM, but try this

```
SELECT authorid, SUM(read) / COUNT(*)
FROM books
GROUP BY authorid
ORDER BY SUM(read) / COUNT(*) DESC
```

This should list all authorids along with the ratio.

Comment: @aF. I did, still looks like a 0 / 1 field to me ; )

Comment: he wants the UNREAD ratio. Your `SUM(read)` will make the READ ratio because read=1 when the author read the book and 0 otherwise. Got it?

Comment: @aF. Maybe the `order by` without `DESC` (and then `limit 1`) is sufficient. Seems correct at the first sight, or is there a flaw?

Comment: @StephanB This solution seems to be right when I change the `order by` but the other solution is more universal (slightly better).

Comment: Yes, I see. Seems I oversimplified.